# Officescript used range issue

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

I am new to Excel office scipt and not sure if there is a limitation running script on xls file vs xlsx file.

Below is my script which doesnt have an issue when I run on xlsx file.
However when I open a xls file it doesnt work and get error message "Line 6: Worksheet getUsedRange: There was an internal error while processing the request."

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  // Get the current worksheet 
  let ws = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  //get active range of WorkSheet
  let range = ws.getUsedRange();
  // Create a table using the data range.
  let newTable = ws.addTable(range, true);
  newTable.setName("TableTKO");
}
```

I have been playing around and so far have observed the following:

- when I save as the file from xls to xlsx it works
- when I copy out the data from xls to a new spreadsheet (xlsx) it works
- if I change the code and hardcode the range it will work

Any ideas why sometimes getting the used range work and is there an alternative of getting the last row/column with out using `let range = ws.getUsedRange()` as I dont want to hard code it?

Thanks

Comment: .xls files and .xlsx are vastly different technologies.  I'd suggest that is why.  Happy to be proven wrong.  Put simply, just work with .xlsx ... .xls was left behind years ago.

Comment: I assume you are working on win32 Excel as Excel online couldn't edit the .xls file. I tried this snippet but seems works well, is this issue happens on all .xls files or just some of them? How big is the UsedRange? Could you share the Office version also?